# How to add Sublime Text command line support for Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, command-line, sublimetext3, osx-elcapitan

How can I (re)enable command line support for Sublime Text under Mac OS X El Capitan ?

Comment: for those who already have a `/usr/local/bin` directory, just running the second part will reenable sublime's cli after upgrading to OS X 10.11 El Capitan: `ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl`

Comment: I have an alias in .bash_aliases

[ alias subl='sublime' ]

Comment: You should form this as a question, and then provide the answer.

Answer (score 30):

To add command line support for Sublime text under Mac OS X El Capitan, open the Terminal.app and run the following command :

```
sudo mkdir -p "/usr/local/bin/" && ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Edit:

In case you already have the directory /usr/local/bin/ on your system, just run the second part of the command (after the &&) :

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Comment: I have the same problem, and this doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 17):

In case of Sublime Text 3:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer from Telmo Bias is quite correct but didn't work.

In my case, i use Sublime Text 2, and here the command :

```
sudo mkdir -p "/usr/local/bin/" && sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Close and reopen the terminal, you should be good to go.

I just tried it before writing this.

Comment: That can't be right as it will create the symbolic link in the current directory.

Comment: You're right, my current was /usr/local/bin.

I corrected the command line

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `subl` or `sublime` from the console to open a file on the system like `/etc/abc.conf`.